# How to capture only backward packets in router with Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I use Python socket to capture packets in Linux as a router.

```
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
while True:
    raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65535)
```

This , capture both forward and backward. for example :

```
forward => packet length:60 , src: 192.168.10.1 , target : 192.168.10.2  
backward => packet length:74 ,src: 192.168.10.2 , target : 192.168.10.1
```

How to capture only backward packets?

```
backward => packet length:74 ,src: 192.168.10.2 , target : 192.168.10.1
```

Comment: Use [`libpcap`](https://pypi.org/project/libpcap/). You can specify filters for packet captures.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly code?

Comment: If *forward* and *backward* happen to correspond with "to the local system" and "from the local system", you might also look into the `bind` parameters explained in the `packet(7)` man page. The `sockaddr_ll` structure contains a field named `sll_pkttype` that allows you to select packets based on their incoming/outgoing status. (Looks like this is available via cPython at least as of 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html?highlight=af_packet)